# Revtex 4-2 ruledtabular

Tags: tables, spacing, revtex

I want to use Revtex 4-2 for a publication. This means I cannot change or reprogram much in the document. But I stumbled across something which is really bugging me concerning the ruledtabular environment.

In Revtex this environment is defined as:

```
\def\toprule{\hline\hline}%
\def\colrule{\hline}%
\def\botrule{\hline\hline}%
\newenvironment{ruledtabular}{%
 \def\array@default{v}%
 \appdef\tabular@hook{\def\@halignto{to\hsize}}%
 \let\tableft@skip@default\tableft@skip
 \let\tableft@skip\tableft@skip@float
 \let\tabmid@skip@default\tabmid@skip
 \let\tabmid@skip\tabmid@skip@float
 \let\tabright@skip@default\tabright@skip
 \let\tabright@skip\tabright@skip@float
 \let\array@row@pre@default\array@row@pre
 \let\array@row@pre\array@row@pre@float
 \let\array@row@pst@default\array@row@pst
 \let\array@row@pst\array@row@pst@float
 \appdef\array@row@rst{%
  \let\array@row@pre\array@row@pre@default
  \let\array@row@pst\array@row@pst@default
  \let\tableft@skip\tableft@skip@default
  \let\tabmid@skip\tabmid@skip@default
  \let\tabright@skip\tabright@skip@default
  \appdef\tabular@hook{\let\@halignto\@empty}%
 }%
}
```

So it adds two \hline at the top and bottom and it aligns its width with the textwidth.
But after using it, you can see that it additionally adds space to the top and bottom. This becomed clear if we compare it to a normal table with two \hline at top and bottom:

```
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{ruledtabular}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    test & test &  test \\
    \hline
    test & test & test \\
    \hline
    test & test & test  \\
   test & test & test  \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
```

in comparison with

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline \hline
    test & test &  test \\
    \hline
    test & test & test \\
    \hline
    test & test & test  \\
   test & test & test  \\
   \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image] [image]

I am now wondering where in the definition of the ruledtabular the extra space at the top and bottom comes from and if this is a bug or a feature? Is it intended from revtex that the top and bottom bars are specially seperated compared to the rest? Because I think it is ugly and in publications from the past the text in the first row is centered.

Answer (score 1):

As far as publications, revtex is the preferred submission form for APS, but it is not used in production to typeset publications. While revtex is generally representative, the exact typesetting will differ and be more representative of recent publications.

To my eye there is an increased space after the top rule in Table 1 of https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.231108, only slightly less pronounced than in revtex, however this is compensated for with better (more even) spacing around the single rule for the row of headings.  The spacing before the bottom rule is not as pronounced as in revtex, probably matching the space before the single rule.

The rules and spacings are input through `\array@row@pre@float` and `\array@row@pst@float` which are defined as

```
\def\array@row@pre@float{\hline\hline\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}}%
\def\array@row@pst@float{\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}\hline\hline}%
```

For preprints or similar, you could remove the spacing by adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\array@row@pre@float{\hline\hline}%
\def\array@row@pst@float{\hline\hline}%
\makeatother
```

to your document. This is unlikely to cause any problems at submission and should simply be ignored by production who will impose their own styles.